# uri.encode full(url) not working on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I want to get data with HTTP on the flap but I have an  issue
Please if anyone can help me

```
String url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/";
  List data;
  var a = Uri.encodeFull(url);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    print(a);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `url` in the class definition. That's what the error is telling you about. You should initialize it in the `initState()`. That's what this method is for.

```
String url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/";
List data;
var a;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  a = Uri.encodeFull(url);
  print(a);    
}
```

Also, look at the documentation of [initState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html). It tells you that "If you override this, make sure your method **starts** with a call to super.initState()".